# How to properly fork a local git repository?

Tags: git, git-fork

I have a local git repo. I want to fork it and use it as the basis of a new project. The new project should never be able to push anything back to the original project. Here is what I *think* I should do...

```
git clone originalproject newproject
git remote remove origin
```

Is there anything else I ought to do to break the link between the two repos and create an independent local fork?

edit: This will work fine locally but if you'd rather link to a new remote repo then see CodeWizard's answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, it will work but instead of removing the origin update it to the new link

```
# Clone the existing project to a new location
git clone originalproject newproject

# Update the remote to the new git repository URL
git remote set-url <remote> <url>
```

---

#### Note

If you have git hooks on your original repository they will not be copied to the new one so you will need to copy them as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Why does it need a "remote" setting if there is no remote repository though?

Comment: No need if there isn't any, but don't you need to keep your work? nowhere to store your changes? if you don't need it you can use `git remote remove ....` as you already did

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how these things are supposed to work. Can't I just keep my work in the local repository I've just cloned? I don't need to share it with anyone else and I take backups so I had been assuming I wouldn't need a remote anything.

Comment: Basically in git you don't need to use remotes. But if you are planning on taking a backup so why not use git instead? if you cant create a git repository so leave it as it is. what you did will work with no problem

Comment: Well I don't have anywhere to put a remote repo right now. AFAIK Github is only free for open source projects and this is a private personal project, for the time being at least. I can always add a remote URL later if I need to right?

Comment: You can have a private repository in github as well. Create a repository and make it private or use settings to set an existing one to private.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200007/discussion-between-technicalbloke-and-codewizard).